# moderncv : \homepage - can't handle a tilde

Tags: urls, tilde, moderncv

I'm using the latest version of `moderncv` from CTAN. When I set :

```
\homepage {homepage: my.homepage.url/~username/}
```

The tilde doesn't show up. So I tried:

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
\homepage {homepage: my.homepage.url/{\texttildelow}username/}
```

But.. that causes an infinite loop:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `baseurl' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 54.


Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfpagemode' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 54.


Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfstartpage' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 54.

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\font@name ->
         \U/mvs/m/n/14.4 
l.55 \maketitle
```

Any Ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the patch! This also works great probably a little cleaner than the other solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
\homepage {homepage: my.homepage.url/\textasciitilde username/}
```

should work.

Comment: @Jake yes it works! It doesn't look as good as \texttildelow but it compiles. Any idea why the other doesn't work?

Comment: @ajpyles: I don't, unfortunately, but this is almost definitely a bug in `moderncv`, which you might want to report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/moderncv

Comment: @jake OK I'll report it. Isn't that the Ubuntu bug reporting page though?

Comment: @ajpyles "launchpad" hosts open source projects, and `moderncv` uses it for the bug tracking. The Ubuntu bug tracker is at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Comment: `\homepage{my.homepage.url/\string~username/}` should work too. If you want a working link you shouldn't add text like "homepage", it will be added to the url. Redefine `\homepagesymbol` instead.

Comment: @jake thanks for clarifying. @Ulrike - yeah I discovered that after posting.

Comment: With the latest version, the leading `homepage: ` should be removed

Answer (score 5):

This happens because this class first saves the `\homepage` argument away and then uses it inside `hyperref`s `\href` macro.

The `~` is then already expanded to an unbreakable space and `\href` doesn't like macros like `\texttilde...` inside the URL part.

Here a small patch of the internally used `\httplink` macro:

```
\renewcommand*\httplink[2][]{{\urlstyle{sf}\expandafter\href#2}}
\homepage{{http://mydomain/~user}{homepage: mydomain/{\texttildelow}user}}                % optional, remove the line if not wanted
```

---

**old:**

Try to use the `\url` macro from the `hyperref` package to format the address correctly:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
%...

\homepage {homepage: \url{http://my.homepage.url/~username/}}
```

Comment: `hyperref` is loaded by `moderncv` automatically, and `\url` is usable in normal entries in the CV, but for me it does not work in `\homepage`, strangely enough...

Comment: I have the same problem. I get an "! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref." must be something weird with moderncv.

Comment: @ajpyles: Try not loading `hyperref` explicitly (it should be loaded by `moderncv`), and then use `\url` in the `\homepage`. That should get rid of the `option clash` error (although I got a different error message in that case, but maybe it works for you).

Comment: @jake doesn't help. I get the same infinite loop listed in the question: ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].